# sqlite | Calculate timestamp difference in the table

Tags: php, sqlite, time

I have a table & trying to calculate time differences between the rows:

[image]

**For example:**

```
Time difference for (rowid: 4) = time (rowid: 3) - time (rowid: 4) = 429168
```

And same for the rest.

**How could I do that?**
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For each row you can get the previous row's time with `LAG()` window function:

```
LAG(time) OVER (ORDER BY id)
```

or:

```
LAG(time, 1, ?) OVER (ORDER BY id)
```

where you replace `?` with the `time` that you want to get when there is no previous row.
The sql statement should be:

```
SELECT *, 
       LAG(time) OVER (ORDER BY id) - time AS difference
FROM tablename;
```